# Joomla auto update

Tags: custom-component, extension-update

Joomla documentation says

Joomla has an additional parameter called extra_query in the #__update_sites table. This parameter will be added to the declared download URL

However when I add ids = kjlsdlkfiuewr87ifdtuyr8237 into the extras field in the update sites table it is not passed as part of $_GET.

Do I need to do something besides add it to the extras column in the table - add code somewhere?

ta

Joomla ref  https://extensions.joomla.org/support/knowledgebase/item/joomla-update-system-requirement/

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.timplummer.com.au/38-how-to-add-joomler-updater-to-commercial-component for more details. Hopefully it will help

Comment: @Lodder - I read his blog and I've done what he suggests but manually.  So I manually added the extra details to the table.  But when it isn't being included in the url by Joomla